# How to incorporate SUBSTITUTE function into complicated function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, regexextract

I have the following function and it works perfectly, with one exception. Some of the values returned have characters in them that I want to remove.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT("|"&REGEXREPLACE(F2:F,"\n","|"),"^"&REPT("\|[^|]*",COLUMN(OFFSET(C1,,,1,5))-1)&"\|([^|]*)")))
```

The string in F2 is: `OER - World History - Day 1 | 9/1/2016 | @ 8:00:00 AM | Location is 000-DO | in Jamacha Conference Room | ID#100008`

The above function currently returns `@ 8:00:00 AM`

I'd like the above function to return `8:00:00 AM`

I've tried using the SUBSTITUTE function on the above function, but I can't figure out 'where' or 'how' to properly use it. If I use it on a simple string, it works perfectly.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(?????, "@ ", "")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have complicated formulas. They make spreadsheets hard to be reviewed and hard to be maintained. Besides this, without sample input data it´s hard to be certain that solution will work and by the other side not all functions are able to work with / on array formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUBSTITUTE(
    IFERROR(
     REGEXEXTRACT(
      "|"&REGEXREPLACE(F2:F,"\n","|"),
      "^"&REPT("\|[^|]*",
      COLUMN(OFFSET(C1,,,1,5))-1)&"\|([^|]*)")
    ),
  "@","")
)
```

## Explanation

The argument of the `ARRAYFORMULA` function, was included as the first argument of `SUBSTITUTE` and this was this was included as argument of the `ARRAYFORMULA`.

NOTE:

Breaklines and indents were included for readability. Google Sheets is able to handle this, but only will keep the breaklines and indents when an argument or function is changed. I recently added a more extended explanation on my answer to [Pretty print google sheet formula?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138044/88163)

Comment: Ruben, thank you for the solution, the explanation, and for sharing the code in a manner that makes it easier to understand. You are the best!